# <filesystem> header library for gcc-c++ on AIX

Tags: aix, gcc, c++, header-file

I'm working on porting some code to AIX from Linux. The code makes use of c++17's  header.

```
#include <filesystem>
...
std::ifstream is(path);
if (!is.is_open() && std::filesystem::path(path).is_relative())
```

The code is compiled using gcc-c++ 8.3.0 on AIX, using the option -std=c++17. The object file the code is in compiles successfully, but when it comes time to link the linker fails with

```
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_M_split_cmpts()
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::has_root_directory() const
```

After searching online, I found out that gcc 8.xx requires the filesystem library to be linked using `-lstdc++fs`, and indeed on Linux the code is compiled with gcc 8.3.1 and that option is used. So I tried again:

```
/opt/freeware/bin/g++ <comand> -lstdc++fs
collect2: fatal error: library libstdc++fs not found
compilation terminated.
```

So my question is, how do I link the filesystem library using gcc-c++ for AIX? Given that my code will compile I'm left assuming that it's possible, but since the linker can't find the library I'm at a loss.

Comment: Untested, but I'm aware of https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/883796 which has `libstdc++` version 8 and seems to include a "filesystem"; I would suggest installing that.

Comment: `sudo yum list libstdc++\*`
`...`
`libstdc++-devel.ppc 8.3.0-2 @AIX_Toolbox_71`

So that is already installed. It seems to not include lstdc++fs, though the one I have on linux does.


Actually if I run a find like `find / -name *stdc++*` on linux I'll get a hit for libstdc++fs, but I'm not getting that on AIX.

Comment: Instead of "`libstdc++-devel`", I intended just "`libstdc++`"

Comment: Did installing `libstdc++` help at all?

Comment: No, it turns out that free software people at IBM simply decided not to include the filesystem header anywhere for their AIX release. So until they add it back there's little chance of this problem being resolved.

See: https://community.ibm.com/community/user/power/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=6211&MessageKey=3d000124-c00d-4e75-abdb-b634897cf8af